# VBA macro hiding sheets

Tags: vba, excel

I know there are answers everywhere for my question but I've tried them all, I'm not sure what I am missing, or what have you. Basically I have about 20 tabs in an excel spreadsheet. On workbook open, I'm trying to hide them all, but this isn't working out. When my workbook opens, i see sheets flashing for a second then everything is like it normally is. I'm basically looping through all the worksheets and making them hidden like this...

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    ws.Visible = xlSheethidden
Next ws

LogForm.Show

End Sub
```

What is it that I'm doing wrong? I'm able to hide them if i simply do...

```
sheets("Project").visible=false
```

But since users might add more worksheets i'm trying to make sure that my code is dynamic.

Comment: It should be `ws.visible = xlSheetHidden`

Comment: IIRC, you cannot hide **every** worksheet. At least one must remain visible. btw, that should be `ThisWorkbook` not `ActiveWorkbook`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hide workbook/worksheets Excel VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39626327/hide-workbook-worksheets-excel-vba)

Comment: If you are displaying a form, rather than hiding sheets, can you not just use `Application.Visible = False`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a few different ways we can go about having the Userform visible while the workbook isn't.

**Minimize your workbook on open.**

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open() 'This is in the Workbook Code
    Application.WindowState = xlMinimized
    UserForm1.Show xlModeless
End Sub
```

**Hide an individual worksheet.**

```
Sub mySub()
    Dim ws as Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)

    ws.Visible = xlSheetHidden
End Sub
```

**Completely hide the Excel Window (Only Userform will show)**

```
Sub mySub()
    UserForm1.Show xlModeless
    Application.Visible = False 'Can also be placed in Workbook_Open() to hide on open
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
    Application.Visible = True
End Sub
```

**To hide a single workbook**

```
Sub MySub()
    Windows("MyWorkbook").Visible = False
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, this is great! The only problem I've come across is ENABLE CONTENT prompt. It seems like no code is executed until user clicks the button, but this is something i can definitely use.